# Does Solr cloud needs a load balancer e.g. HAPROXY in master failure

Tags: solr, load-balancing, haproxy, solrcloud

I have searched a lot but unfortunately have some simple confusion about solr cloud. Lets say, I have three systems where solrCloud in configured (1 master and 2 slave) and external Zookeeper on same three machines to make a quorum. Systems names are

- master
- slave1
- slave2
- Public-Front

The Public-Front is the system where, I have configured HAPROXY. It receives requests from WWW and the send to backend server depending on ACLs.

According to my understanding, If I request to Solr collection (i.e., master), it routes it to slaves and hence load balanced. There is no need to specify slaves here. Isn't ?

Now in Public-Front, should I configured each Solr as a separate slave to load balance or just to master system.

Now if I only configure master system as solr-server in HAPROXY then if solr-server (master) goes down then I think I cannot get service from Solr from HAPROXY (although slaves are till up but not configured in HAPROXY).

Where am I wrong and what is the best approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no traditional `master` or `slave` in Solr Cloud - there is a set of replicas, one of which is defined as the leader. The leader selection is automagic - i.e. the first replica that says it wants to be the leader, receives that status. This is per collection state. In your example there is three replicas, one which is designed as the leader. If that replica disappears, one of the two remaining replicas becomes the new leader, and everything continues as normal. The role of the leader is to be the up-to-date version of the index and handle any updates - [first to its own index, then route those updates to any replicas](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/shards-and-indexing-data-in-solrcloud.html#types-of-replicas).

There is also [several types of replicas](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/shards-and-indexing-data-in-solrcloud.html#types-of-replicas), and not all of them are suited to be promoted to a leader - but in the default configuration they can be.

Here's the thing - since there isn't really a master, all three indexes contain the same data and they all are replicas of the same shard, the request won't have to be routed through the master. If you're using a dumb haproxy, you can safely spread the requests across all three nodes and they should be able to answer the query without contacting any other nodes (as long as they all contain all the shards of the collection).

However, if you're using SolrJ or another Zookeeper capable client (and using the Zookeeper compatible client), the client will keep in touch with Zookeeper instead, and read the state information for your cluster. That allows the client to know which servers are currently replicas for your collection, and contact any of those nodes that it can decide have the required information for your query. In your case the result will be the same, except that your client will know not to connect to any nodes that disappear and will automagically know about nodes that are added to the cluster.

The "one Solr node routing requests to a different node" is only relevant if the node you're contacting doesn't have any replicas for the collection you're querying - i.e. it'll have to contact a different node to fetch that content. In that case an inter cluster request will happen and the load on the cluster will be slightly higher than necessary. When the collection is replicated to all three nodes - or when you're using SolrJ, that inter cluster request should not happen.